# print via system() in perl via xampp (windows-7-x64) not working

Tags: perl, xampp, windows-7-x64

I need to print a generated text-file with perl. I'm using xampp, Windows7 64 bit.
My perl-script is containing the print system call:

```
$system = "print\ /d:\\\\SERVER\\PRINTER\ C:\\xampp\\cgi-bin\\textfile.txt";
system ($system);
```

When i try the same line in the cmd-shell, the print works.

The answer is:

```
C:\xampp\cgi-bin\textfile.txt wird momentan gedruckt.
```

but nothing else happens.

I then tried to create a batch-file. Starting the batch-file manually starts the print. From a system()-call nothing happens.

Then i tried another way, showing the file in Firefox first. I copied the file to my htdocs-dir and changed my batch-file to:

```
cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
firefox.exe -new-window http://localhost/textfile.txt
```

Doubleclicking the bat starts my firefox and my textfile.
The system()-call ist not working.

Any Ideas?

Tom

Comment: Did you forget to escape the last backslash (near `cgi-bin\textfile.txt`) ?

Comment: Yes, thanks! But only in my posted question :-( In my real code it is escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My brother found the reason. THANKS CHRIS!
It was a problem with the permissions.
The apache service is running without normal user permissions.
To set user permissions (or, better: special defined, new permissions) in Windows 7 pro 64 bit:
(Sorry, this is german)

Task-Manager
"Dienste"
rechts unten auf "[Adminzeichen] Dienste"
Auf Dienst "Apache" rechtsklick "Eigenschaften"
Reiter: "Anmelden"
Auswahl: "Dieses Konto"
User und Passwort rein
"Übernehmen" und "OK"

Dann nochmal auf "Apache" linksklick und links auf "neu starten"